# Why does the mid point formula work no matter what the sign of coordinates are?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

This question is asked by my 12 yr old cousin and I seem to be failing to give him a convincing explanation. Here is the summary of our discussion so far -

Case1 : $a>0, b>0$
[image]

I asked him to put another block of length $a$ adjacent to $b$ and stare at the symmetry. He quickly told me that the mid point of $a, b$ equals half the length of $a+b$ :
[image]

So far we're good. But when either one of $a,b$ is negative, I feel stuck. I fail to give him a similar explanation using symmetry. Greatly appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: The same, but put the extra block of size $a$ at the end of $b$ but with its orientation. Meaning, the block starts at the right end of $b$ and extends to the left of that end, overlapping $b$. That is what adding a negative number means anyway.

Comment: Oh do you mean put the extra block of size $a$ overlapping $b$ ? That will do I guess !

Comment: I've never seriously thought about this geometry interpretation before, but for some reason it looks amazing the same formula works even when $a$ is negative and $b$ is positive! Ty :)

Comment: When geometry gets confusing, algebra can help. The mid point $x$ satisfies that $|a-x|=|b-x|$, same distance from $a$ and $b$. From there $a^2-2ax+x^2=(a-x)^2=(b-x)^2=b^2-2bx+x^2$. It follows that $x=\frac{a^2-b^2}{2(a-b)}=\frac{a+b}{2}$.

Comment: Ah midpoint will be at same distance from both $a$ and $b$. Looks neat!

Comment: I would say that the midpoint is at $$a+\frac{b-a}2=\frac a2+\frac b2=\frac{a+b}2$$ if $b>a$. $\frac{b-a}2$ is the half of the distance between the points.

This may be hard to understand if the child is not completely familiar with the concept of negative numbers.

Comment: @zoli this form looks more better. I feel this form is best for explaining - you add half the the distance between $a$ and $b$ to your starting point $a$. Ty :)

Comment: Also to add this is sometimes used in equation solving or in integration to make thing symmetrical..

Answer (score 1):

Given two points $a<b$ on the number line the midpoint $m$ of the two is characterized by the fact that there is a common increment $d>0$ such that $$a=m-d,\qquad b=m+d\ .$$
This gives $m={a+b\over2}$ without looking at the signs of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

Slide the $a$-$b$ block around on the number line. I’m sure that your cousin would agree that the coordinates of any point on this rigid block, and in particular its end- and mid-points, change by the same amount. So, if you have $m=\frac12(a+b)$ with both $a$ and $b$ nonnegative, after sliding the block a distance of $\Delta$ (with $\Delta<0$ meaning you slide to the left), by applying the associative and commutative laws of addition, and the distributive law of multiplication over addition to the midpoint formula you get $${(a+\Delta)+(b+\Delta) \over 2} = \frac12(a+b)+\frac12(\Delta+\Delta) = m+\Delta$$ as required. This holds regardless of how large $\Delta$ is, so the formula applies for any combination of signs of the coordinates.